# Confusing $tag specification for apply_filters call, in core options.php code

Tags: plugin-development, filters

I was reading through `/wp-admin/options.php` and came across a `$tag` specification inside a call to `apply_filters`, which I do not understand.  I looked at the source for [apply_filters](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/plugin.php#L199) as well, to try to figure it out...no joy.

This bit of code from `options.php`, line 44:

```
34 /**
35 * Filter the capability required when using the Settings API.
36 *
37 * By default, the options groups for all registered settings require the manage_options capability.
38 * This filter is required to change the capability required for a certain options page.
39 *
40 * @since 3.2.0
41 *
42 * @param string $capability The capability used for the page, which is manage_options by default.
43 */
44 $capability = apply_filters( "option_page_capability_{$option_page}", $capability );
```

I understand what it purports to be doing, but I don't understand why the `$tag` spec:

`"option_page_capability_{$option_page}"`

is not like this:

`"option_page_capability_" . $option_page`

I don't see how it is being resolved to the value inside the variable `$option_page`, if it is being passed as a string containing the text of the variable name itself, enclosed by curly brackets?

I trust it is working correctly but I don't like not knowing why it works with that syntax.

Comment: [These notes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php#60035) might help.

Comment: ah, thanks Dan.  I had no idea that was an alternate concatenation syntax for PHP.